# Android - ListView layout two line list item

Tags: android, listview, textview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `listview` with two lines of items: user ID and username. How to retrieve only user ID from the `listview` when one of the rows is clicked?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mUsers;
String getValue = null;
ListView lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_USERS);

    FirebaseListAdapter<Users> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Users>(
            this, Users.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mUsers
    ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Users user, int pos) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(user.getUserID());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(user.getUsername());
            }
    };

    lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
    setupListViewMenu(); 
}

private void setupListViewMenu() {
    lvUsers.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                       View item, int pos, long id) {

            // How to retrieve only User ID from here?
            getValue = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            return true;
        }

    });
}
}
```

The `listview` data is from Firebase database. Is retrieving using `for loop` the only way? I have to loop through two dimensional array? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the code below?

```
getValue = ((TextView)item.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
```

I believe that `android.R.id.text2` is one of the childs of `item`(`View` received in the clickListener)

But need to test... Hope it works